# Java ByteBuffer in C?

Tags: java, c, bytebuffer

I need to translate a Java method, which uses the ByteBuffer object to C. How can I accurately replicate the code below using Java's ByteBuffer? And what data types should I use to embed floats in a byte array (in C)?

The code I spoke about:

```
public void example(float[] floatData) {
    //Initialize byte array "byteData"
    byte[] byteData = new byte[floatData.length * 4];
    ByteBuffer byteDataBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteData);
    byteDataBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

    //Fill byte array with data from floatData
    for (int i = 0; i < floatData.length; i++)
    byteDataBuffer.putFloat(floatData[i]);

    //Concat length of array (as byte array) to "byteData"
    byte[] vL = intToByteArray(floatData.length / 2);
    byte[] v = concatArrays(vL, byteData);

    //Fill the remaining array with empty bytes
    if (v.length < 1024) {
        int zeroPad = 1024 - v.length;
        byte[] zeroArray = new byte[zeroPad];
        v = concatArrays(v, zeroArray);
        zeroArray = null;
    }

    //[Do something with v[] here...]
}
```

FloatData[] can look something like this: 1.00052387686001,-1.9974419759404,0.996936345285375

Comment: Use `calloc` to allocate the space (1024). Set the length as the first sizeof(int) bytes, then use `memcpy` to copy the float array over to the rest of the allocated memory (sizeof(float)*length). I don't see a `p[]` anywhere?

Comment: Yes i removed that last minute, because it wasn't relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `calloc` to allocate the space (1024). Set the length as the first `sizeof(int)` bytes, then use `memcpy` to copy the float array over to the rest of the allocated memory (`sizeof(float)*length`).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void example(float * fAry, int length){
    int i;
    unsigned char* bAry = calloc(1024,1);

    memcpy(bAry,&length,sizeof(int));    
    memcpy(bAry + sizeof(int), fAry, length*(sizeof(float)));

    for (i=0; i<20; i++){
        printf("%u,",bAry[i]);
    }

    free(bAry);
}


int main()
{
    float ary[3] ={1.1,1.2,1.3};

    example(ary,3);

    return 0;
}
```

output:

> 3,0,0,0,205,204,140,63,154,153,153,63,102,102,166,63,0,0,0,0,